# Ajax Request not completing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

i am making a form to subscribe newsletter, for this i am using ajax request to call mailchimp api. api is working fine alone, i have tested it.
but in ajax code i alert in beforeSend and complete section it went right,but in success it does nothing.

here is my code:

**HTML Form Code**

```
<form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="useremail" placeholder="Type our mail address" required>
    <input type="button" value="subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="mc-button" >
      <div id="subscribe-result">
      </div>
</form>
```

**Script Code**

```
<script>
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe").click(function() { 

var email = $('#useremail').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "newslatter.php", 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'useremail='+email,
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    complete: function() {
    },  
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("enter success");
        if(data.type == 'error')
        {
            output = "<a color='red'>"+data.text+"</div>";
        }else{
            output = data.text;
        }
        $("#subscribe-result").html(output);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

and Here Is **PHP Code of NewsLatter**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    //exit script outputting json data
    $output = json_encode(
            array(
                'type' => 'error',
                'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
    ));

    die($output);
}

//check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
if ( !isset($_POST["useremail"]) ) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
    die($output);
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$useremail = filter_var(trim($_POST["useremail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//additional php validation

if (!filter_var($useremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
$list_id = '***secret***';
$api_key = '***secret***';


$data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);

$url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';

$json = json_encode([
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
]);


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);


if ($status_code!=200) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Something Went Wrong'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Hi ' . $username . ' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}





?>
```

Comment: Any errors on the console? Did you try adding in an error callback and checking the `textStatus` argument?

Comment: sir there is no error in console

Comment: as i said above i tried alert in all section everywhere it works left sucess section

Comment: And as I said, try adding in an error callback and see if it fire there if it does check the `textStatus` argument

Comment: sir error callback is also not responding and nothing in console.

Comment: i did it like this  error: function () {
            alert("Enter in errror");
        }

Comment: What is in textStatus of complete? complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert(textStatus);},

Comment: it says parsererror

Comment: What about text of error? complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert(jqXHR.responseText);},

Comment: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\trademark\newslatter.php on line <i>73</i></th></tr>
</table></font>

Comment: There is unclosed bracket of block if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

Comment: Add one } at the end of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in this line

```
$json = json_encode([
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
]);
```

variable name is **$useremail**, not $email so change it to

```
 $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $useremail,
        'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
    ]);
```

Newletter code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
            array(
                'type' => 'error',
                'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
            ));
        die($output);
    }
    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if ( !isset($_POST["useremail"]) ) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $useremail = filter_var(trim($_POST["useremail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    //additional php validation
    if (!filter_var($useremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    $list_id = '***secret***';
    $api_key = '***secret***';
    $data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $useremail,
        'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
    ]);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($status_code!=200) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Something Went Wrong'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Hi ' . $username . ' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: it throws this error in complete section:    <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\trademark\newslatter.php on line <i>68</i></th></tr>
</table></font>

Comment: because there is closing bracket error in file. updated code above. it is working fine in my local

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

in php before sending json response

Also one curly brace "}" needed at the and of file to close the block

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

Comment: Try to add return true; in beforeSend callback. beforeSend: function() { return true; }

Comment: no sir nothing happen and it didn't give error at all.